# Validate multiple upload images with django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to upload multiple images using a form with django. I manage to allow the user to upload them, but when I validate the form I always get the message that the I need to upload an image, but I can see that `request.FILES` contains all the uploaded images.

Here is my form:

```
class ProductForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = ['name', 'style', 'description', 'buy_url', 'price', 'currency', 'images']
        error_messages = {
            NON_FIELD_ERRORS: {
                'buy_url': "%(model_name)s's %(field_labels)s are not unique.",
            }
        }
        widgets = {
            'description': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}),
            'images': FileInput(attrs={'multiple': ''})
        }
```

and Here the view:

```
class CreateProductView(AuthenticatedUserView):
    template_name = 'myapp/product.html'

    def get_if_authenticated(self, request, user):
        form = ProductForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})

    def post_if_authenticated(self, request, user):
        form = ProductForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            product = form.save(commit=False)
            # Here do something with the images
            product.user = user
            product.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp:actions'))

        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

I've tried to add the method `clean_images` but it is never called.

How can I successfully validate the FILES in the post request?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I revoke my answer. I no longer want to support this site.